# how to group and display

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table data like below

```
componenet                  data 

Med1rbtCompliant                Y
Med1tbxCurrentRegimen       poiuy
Med1tbxDosage               iuyt
Med1tbxEfficancy               oiuy
Med1tbxMonthsOfMedication   oiuyt
Med1tbxSideEffects           oiuy
Med2rbtCompliant                Y
Med2tbxDosage               iuytre
Med2tbxEfficancy               poiu
```

By SQL I want to get

```
Compliant   CurrentRegimen   Dosage  Efficancy  MonthsOfMedication
y            poiuy           iuyt     oiuy       oiuyt
y                            iuytre   poiu
```

Is it possible to get like this in SQL?

Note: here id is unique and I am getting the data by here and binding in gridview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it this way

```
select
  max(case when component like '%rbtCompliant' then data else null end)  as Compliant,
  max(case when component like '%tbxCurrentRegimen' then data else null end)  as CurrentRegimen,
  max(case when component like '%tbxDosage' then data else null end)  as Dosage,
  max(case when component like '%tbxEfficancy' then data else null end)  as Efficancy,
  max(case when component like '%tbxMonthsOfMedication' then data else null end)  as MonthsOfMedication
from your_table
```

If you have more than one case, you need to group by the key of the table, which doesn't appear in your sample data. Something like this...

```
select
  your_table.id,
  max(case when component like '%rbtCompliant' then data else null end)  as Compliant,
  max(case when component like '%tbxCurrentRegimen' then data else null end)  as CurrentRegimen,
  max(case when component like '%tbxDosage' then data else null end)  as Dosage,
  max(case when component like '%tbxEfficancy' then data else null end)  as Efficancy,
  max(case when component like '%tbxMonthsOfMedication' then data else null end)  as MonthsOfMedication
from your_table
group by your_table.id
```

Comment: Med1 ,Med2 ,Med3 first 4 letter dynamic bro . what to do in this case

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that detail, I have changed the query

Comment: i check by where Id ='247635'  ,it id have med1 ,med2 set . in this case med1 set only returning bro . second line missing

Comment: It's impossible with the sample data and expected output reach that conclusions... In the new case that you explain, you would need to group by the id and also by the first letters of the `component` column (`'MedXXX'`)

Comment: Somethin like this could work... 
`group by your_table.id,   
  left(component,
    case charindex('r',component,0)
    when 0 then charindex('t',component,0) 
    else charindex('r',component,0)
  end - 1
  )`

Answer (score 1):

This is rather tricky, because your key has a prefix.  What you can do is aggregate by that prefix:

```
select max(case when component like '%rbtCompliant' then data end) as Compliant,
       max(case when component like '%tbxCurrentRegimen' then data end)  as CurrentRegimen,
       max(case when component like '%tbxDosage' then data end) as Dosage,
       max(case when component like '%tbxEfficancy' then data end) as Efficancy,
       max(case when component like '%tbxMonthsOfMedication' then data end) as MonthsOfMedication
from t
group by left(component, 4);
```